# Not able to Inject Javascript in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I get a 404 for a JavaScript file that I am trying to inject in my swagger. Following is my swagger config

```
var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API");
        })
    .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
        {
            c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly,"MyApi.Api.SwaggerExtensions.inject.js");   
        });
```

For inject.js build action is set to embedded resource and logical path is correct as my project name is MyApi.Api and the file is in a folder within the project named SwaggerExtensions

Comment: What URL are you using that returns a 404? Do you know Swashbuckle generates this URL: `swagger/ui/ext/MyApi-Api-SwaggerExtensions-inject-js`?

Comment: I am aware and I am getting a 404 on
/swagger/ui/ext/MyApi-Api-SwaggerExtensions-inject-js?_=1483663626890

Comment: Ok. Another shot then: is `MyApi.Api` the default namespace of your project?

Comment: No my default namespace is `AcctMgmt`

Comment: In that case the string should be "AcctMgmt.SwaggerExtensions.inject.js" as described [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/#injecting-custom-content)

Comment: @venerik That worked like a charm. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I promoted my comments to an answer. Answered questions are appreciated more on Stackoverflow than unanswered questions (and I can get reputation points for it :-)

Comment: Ensure your Javascript file is an embedded resource also!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using custom resources the resource name should contain the default namespace of your project as described [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/#injecting-custom-content). In your case the configuration should be:

```
c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "AcctMgmt.SwaggerExtensions.inject.js")
```

Comment: Attention!! In the "inject.js" right click on the file and select properties and set its Build Action to “Embedded Resource”

Comment: @venerik I'm facing the same issue as @coder32; 404 error. The default namespace is 'TestAPI' and the path of the inject.js is:'TestAPI\SwaggerExtensions\inject.js'. The file is set as "Embedded Resource" as well The InjectJavaScript line is: options.InjectJavascript("TestAPI.SwaggerExtensions.inject.js"); Could you explain which setting or name I need to modify to solve the issue?

Comment: What's the exact URL that's giving the 404?

Comment: 2021 Update - this answer works with the 4.X full framework version

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out that a method with the same name has a different behavior. The config in Startup.Configure expects a relative path from wwwroot:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    //
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Salon API v1");
        c.InjectJavascript("/SwaggerExtension.js");
    });
}
```

[Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with .NET 6.

The solution was to include a `wwwroot` folder in the `WebApi` project and add all the custom files to that folder. The rest of the Swagger configuration is as simple as it gets.

Directory of custom files: `wwwroot/OpenApi/CustomScript.js`

Swagger configuration:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
    c.InjectJavascript("/OpenApi/CustomScript.js");
});
```

Don't forget to enable `UseStaticFiles` middleware.

For the `Build action` of these custom files it seems to work with both options: `None` and `Embedded resource`.

Hope this helps anyone having the same issue.

P.S. I know that adding a `wwwroot` folder seems redundant and I agree. If anyone finds a way around it, let me know.